# winscp.exe ftp://.... /rawsettings ProxyHost

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, ftp, winscp

I'm trying to specify proxy related settings while  starting WinSCP GUI from cmd.
I've used following command
`WinSCP.exe ftp://USER:PASS@HOST /log=H:winscptest.log /rawsettings ProxyHost=PROXYHOST` (I would like to specify also password this way) and setting log file works perfectly fine but in this log file I can see `Proxy: None` and this is causing `Connection failed`

Any example of battle proven command properly setting proxy configuration variables will be much welcomed.

In fact I will also be happy of any way of starting WinSCP GUI after providing proxy user and password  as well as ftp user and password programmatically ( having as input for the powershell/batch program those values in plain text )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set [`ProxyMethod`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings#proxymethod) according to your proxy type (HTTP/SOCKS/...). Without that, `ProxyHost` has not effect.

An example for HTTP proxy:

```
WinSCP.exe ftp://USER:PASS@HOST/ /rawsettings ProxyMethod=3 ProxyHost=PROXYHOST /log=...
```